# Column that matches in a fulltext index spanning multiple columns

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, matching, full-text-indexing

I am using the latest version of MySQL 5.5.

I have a fulltext index spanning multiple columns in a table generated specifically for fulltext search (other tables in the database uses innodb):

```
somedata_search
========
id
name
about
note
dislike
```

I have a fulltext index on all the columns except for ID. I am able to run fulltext searches using:

```
 SELECT * FROM account_search WHERE MATCH(name, about, note, dislike) AGAINST('mykeyword*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This all works fine, but is there a way to deteremine which column the match originates from for each row? If there are matches across columns in a row, I am happy to have just the first column.

Comment: what you want to achieve if you want to check match of each colum against something then do it in four different querry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any "native" way of getting it but it is possible to do it anyway.

I'm not sure this is fast but it returns the correct data

```
select text_test.*,
       match(name) against ('dude' in boolean mode) as name_match, 
       match(info) against ('dude' in boolean mode) as info_match 
  from text_test 
 where match(name, info) against ('dude' in boolean mode);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5159c/1